# Text changing back to original after 'swap' function Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a bit stumped on this :

**Context**

I have a 'workout session' which is in a `tableView` inside a `UIViewController`.  Each `cell` has an `exercise name`, `number of reps` and a `swap button`.  The `swap button` generates a new exercise from the exercise bank (i.e. if it says "bench press" but you don't have a bench press then you can swap it for something else).

**Problem**

My `swap button` code works and a new exercise populates the cell.  However, when I press "Play" on my workout timer, it resets to what it was before!

**Code - swap button**

```
func swapButtonTapped(cell: WorkoutCell) {
    let realmExercisePool = realm.objects(ExerciseGeneratorObject.self)
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(realmExercisePool.count)))
    let newExercise = realmExercisePool[index].generateExercise()
    cell.exerciseName.text = newExercise.name
    cell.repsNumber.text = String(newExercise.reps)
}
```

**Code - Timer**

```
@IBAction func timerControlTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {    
    if isTimerRunning == false {
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "timerPause"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        runTimer()
        isTimerRunning = true
        swapButtonEnabled = false
        workoutTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "timerPlay"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        workoutTimerObject.invalidate()
        isTimerRunning = false
    }
}
```

**Code - Run Timer**

```
func runTimer() {
    workoutTimerObject = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(WorkoutViewController.workoutTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    isTimerRunning = true
}
```

The original group of exercises are passed in an `array` of `workoutExercises` from the previous VC (a 'workout set up screen')
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has a similar problem, I managed to work this out.

This was happening because I was simply changing the 'content' of the cell in my `swapButtonTapped` and not the actual data source.

When I then called "`reloadData()`" in `timerControlTapped`, it was reloading the original data.

What I needed to do was replace the actual data by replacing the exercise at the selected index with a new one in the "`selectedWorkoutExerciseArray`".

I used this code :

```
func swapButtonTapped(cell: WorkoutCell) {

    let myIndexPath = workoutTableView.indexPath(for: cell)

    let realmExercisePool = realm.objects(ExerciseGeneratorObject.self)
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(realmExercisePool.count)))
    let newExercise = realmExercisePool[index].generateExercise()

    selectedWorkoutExerciseArray[(myIndexPath?.row)!] = newExercise

    cell.exerciseName.text = newExercise.name
    cell.repsNumber.text = String(newExercise.reps)

}
```